# jQuery Mobile page - accessed directly or loaded by Ajax?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Is there any way I can determine if a page that uses jQuery Mobile was loaded by Ajax by that framework, or was accessed directly by its URL?

Just to clarify my question and requirement, I would like to change a couple of things on the page (i.e. a couple of elements within ) based on how the page was accessed. Currently I am handling the pageload event but that doesn't seem to be triggered when I'm accessing the page directly, i.e by typing the URL in the address bar. I need something I can use in code to determine how the page was accessed.

I have also tried `$('#pageId').on('pageinit', function(event){ blah });` but I can't seem to get where I came from from the event object... unless I missed something.

UPDATE: Ok, the solution was to decorate the page with all the styles and include content for the "direct access" condition, and when navigated to from another jQuery Mobile page I handle the `pageload` event and change content and styles accordingly. I'd still like to know if there's a way I can detect how the page was accessed though. NOTE: I am referring to "page", which is a jQuery Mobile construct, NOT the entire document.

Comment: Can you describe the problem in more details? What do you want to achieve??

Answer (score 1):

Ajax requests should have HTTP Header called `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` set to `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: Cool, but I'm referring to a jQuery Mobile "page", not the entire document. Excuse my javascript noobness but I'm not sure how I can get hold of the headers in the various jQuery Mobile events.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution From the device

1. Disable Javascript, Load the page, see what shows up.
2. Go offline, Reanable Javascript , see what shows up.

Comment: Please see the updates to my question for further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

### From a computer use Firfox, with the firebug extension, and Yslow.

With firebug & yslow

- You will be able to assess all the related files of the source code,  and explore them.
- Under the Network tab you can see if any ajax querys are made,whats load up and what's going on with the source when it's run.

Supported platforms:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/about/platforms.html

Comment: Please see the updates to my question for further clarification.